# [PDFBox]-Obtain the boundaries of the clipping area of an image in a PDF file

Tags: java, pdfbox

This is my first post in this forum, so please excuse me if I couldn't explain my problem clearly.

I am trying the extract the images from a PDF file using Apache PDFBox. At the same time, I want to obtain the boundaries of the area that appears on screen (the area clipped from the original image)

I started with [PrintImageLocations.java](https://svn.apache.org/viewvc/pdfbox/trunk/examples/src/main/java/org/apache/pdfbox/examples/util/PrintImageLocations.java?view=markup) example.

The problem I am facing is that the coordinations obtained by the TransformationMatrix are for the image itself NOT for the area clipped in it.

[image: an image inserted in PDF]

I appreciate any help or hint about the way to find the coordinations of the green rectangle in the attached image.

Comment: `PrintImageLocations` only registers listeners for operators necessary to determine the location and orientation of the actual image but not any clip path related once. For that you have to register additional listeners. For those listeners your class had better be derived from `PDFGraphicsStreamEngine` (instead of `PDFStreamEngine` like `PrintImageLocations` is) with pre-defined abstract callback methods. The `PageDrawer` can be taken as template for the path defining and clipping operations.

Comment: Thank you @mkl for the information. I will have a look at the classes you kindly suggested (`PDFGraphicsStreamEngine` and `PageDrawer`)